# How to handle optional beanproerty in jmx_exporter rule

Tags: regex, prometheus, jmx-exporter

I want to in the jmx_exporter configuration formulate a rule for the JMX datasources metircs
such as:

```
# HELP catalina_datasource_testonborrow Catalina:name="jdbc/AgentDesktopDS",type=DataSource,attribute=TestOnBorrow
# TYPE catalina_datasource_testonborrow untyped
catalina_datasource_testonborrow{host="worker1",context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",class="javax.sql.DataSource",name="\"jdbc/AgentDesktopDS\"",connectionpool="connections",} 1.0
catalina_datasource_testonborrow{host="worker1",context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",class="javax.sql.DataSource",name="\"jdbc/AgentDesktopCommLogDS\"",connectionpool="connections",} 1.0
catalina_datasource_testonborrow{host="worker1",context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",class="javax.sql.DataSource",name="\"jdbc/AgentDesktopReportsDS\"",connectionpool="connections",} 1.0
catalina_datasource_testonborrow{host="worker1",context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",class="javax.sql.DataSource",name="\"jdbc/AgentDesktopCommLogDS\"",} 1.0
catalina_datasource_testonborrow{host="worker1",context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",class="javax.sql.DataSource",name="\"jdbc/AgentDesktopDS\"",} 1.0
catalina_datasource_testonborrow{host="worker1",context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",class="javax.sql.DataSource",name="\"jdbc/AgentDesktopReportsDS\"",} 1.0
catalina_datasource_testonborrow{host="worker1",context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",class="javax.sql.DataSource",name="\"jdbc/AgentDesktop_AdministrationDS\"",} 1.0
catalina_datasource_testonborrow{host="worker1",context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",class="javax.sql.DataSource",name="\"jdbc/AgentDesktop_CarDS\"",} 1.0
catalina_datasource_testonborrow{host="worker1",context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",class="javax.sql.DataSource",name="\"jdbc/AgentDesktop_AirDS\"",} 1.0
catalina_datasource_testonborrow{host="worker1",context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",class="javax.sql.DataSource",name="\"jdbc/AgentDesktop_CoreDS\"",} 1.0
```

My problem is how to handle the optional connectionpool property, which appears only is some of the metrics data.
The best I could come up until now is a pattern like this:

```
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: true
lowercaseOutputName: true
rules:
- pattern: 'Catalina<type=DataSource, host=([-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:.,;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]), context=([-a-zA-Z0-9+/$%~_-|!.]*), class=javax.sql.DataSource, name="(.*)"(.*)><>(.*):'
  name: tomcat_datasource_$5
  labels:
    context: $2
    host: $1
    blah: $4
    # pool: $6
    datasource: $3
  help: Tomcat session $5
  type: GAUGE
```

which gives me

```
# HELP tomcat_datasource_testonborrow Tomcat session TestOnBorrow
# TYPE tomcat_datasource_testonborrow gauge
tomcat_datasource_testonborrow{blah=", connectionpool=connections",context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",datasource="jdbc/AgentDesktopDS",host="worker1",} 1.0
tomcat_datasource_testonborrow{blah=", connectionpool=connections",context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",datasource="jdbc/AgentDesktopCommLogDS",host="worker1",} 1.0
tomcat_datasource_testonborrow{blah=", connectionpool=connections",context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",datasource="jdbc/AgentDesktopReportsDS",host="worker1",} 1.0
tomcat_datasource_testonborrow{context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",datasource="jdbc/AgentDesktopCommLogDS",host="worker1",} 1.0
tomcat_datasource_testonborrow{context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",datasource="jdbc/AgentDesktopDS",host="worker1",} 1.0
tomcat_datasource_testonborrow{context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",datasource="jdbc/AgentDesktopReportsDS",host="worker1",} 1.0
tomcat_datasource_testonborrow{context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",datasource="jdbc/AgentDesktop_AdministrationDS",host="worker1",} 1.0
tomcat_datasource_testonborrow{context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",datasource="jdbc/AgentDesktop_CarDS",host="worker1",} 1.0
tomcat_datasource_testonborrow{context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",datasource="jdbc/AgentDesktop_AirDS",host="worker1",} 1.0
tomcat_datasource_testonborrow{context="/AgentDesktop_lcr",datasource="jdbc/AgentDesktop_CoreDS",host="worker1",} 1.0
```

Group 4 works as a catch all-
But when I tried to replace this with something like

```
- pattern: 'Catalina<type=DataSource, host=([-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:.,;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]), context=([-a-zA-Z0-9+/$%~_-|!.]*), class=javax.sql.DataSource, name="(.*)"(, connectionpool=(.*))?><>(.*):'
```

I got only the lines with or the lines without the connectionpool property.

Is there a way to make the optional pattern work

Comment: I find this part very strange: "I got only the lines with or the lines without the connectionpool property". I doubt you got both results from the same regex. Can you show both attempts and specify which lead to which result?

Comment: Have you tried something like this: `name="(.*?)"(?:, connectionpool=(.*?))?><>(.*):`?

Comment: Yes I tried `name="(.*?)"(, connectionpool=(.*?))?><>(.*):`.  But it did no work for me. Any how I will try the and your suggestion again and post the results.